# Edit row values for many dummy variables

Tags: r, dummy-variable

This is how my data looks:

[image: Input]

My dput is given below as:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 6), country = c("US", "JP","CH", "US", "KR", "KR"), US = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), JP = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CH = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), KR = c(0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0), BE = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

**This is what I want:**

[image]

Running `data2[levels(factor(data2$country))] = model.matrix(~country - 1, data2)` gives me a close but WRONG result:

[image]

How can I get the structure that I'm looking for? Please help; I've been working on this problem for days and no advice I've gotten has been close to what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do it using `lapply` and `sapply`

```
#Get Matches for column name and country variable

matches <- lapply(colnames(df[-(1:2)]), \(x) df$country %in% x)


#Get the id for each match

ids <- lapply(matches, \(x) df$id[x])

#add 1 to each

df[-(1:2)] <- sapply(ids, \(x) +(df$id %in% x))
```

or in one go

```
df[-(1:2)] <- sapply(lapply(lapply(colnames(df[-(1:2)]), 
                                   \(x) df$country %in% x),
                            \(x) df$id[x]), 
                     \(x) +(df$id %in% x))
```

```
  id country US JP CH KR BE SP
1  1      US  1  1  0  0  0  0
2  1      JP  1  1  0  0  0  0
3  3      CH  1  0  1  0  0  0
4  3      US  1  0  1  0  0  0
5  5      KR  0  0  0  1  0  0
6  6      KR  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Here we first group by `id`, then assign 1 to to each column that has same name as the row in country.
2. Next step is a trick: we use `fill` to get 1 for each row of 1 in the group
3. Next we bring back the NA to 0

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(across(-country, ~case_when(country == cur_column() ~ 1))) %>% 
  fill(-country, .direction = "updown") %>% 
  mutate(across(-country, ~ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

output:

```
     id country    US    JP    CH    KR    BE    SP
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 US          1     1     0     0     0     0
2     1 JP          1     1     0     0     0     0
3     3 CH          1     0     1     0     0     0
4     3 US          1     0     1     0     0     0
5     5 KR          0     0     0     1     0     0
6     6 KR          0     0     0     1     0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue in the OP's code seems to be related to the `class` of 'country' which is `character`.  We may need to convert to `factor` before doing the `model.matrix` and include the `levels` based on the column names in 'data2'.  Also, wrapping `factor` on the 'data2$country' will have only the values from that column (as some of them are still missing based on the column names)

```
data2$country <- factor(data2$country, levels = names(data2)[-(1:2)])
m1 <-  model.matrix(~country - 1, data2)
m1[] <- ave(c(m1), data2$id[row(m1)], col(m1), FUN = max)
data2[levels(data2$country)] <- m1
```

-output

```
> data2
  id country US JP CH KR BE SP
1  1      US  1  1  0  0  0  0
2  1      JP  1  1  0  0  0  0
3  3      CH  1  0  1  0  0  0
4  3      US  1  0  1  0  0  0
5  5      KR  0  0  0  1  0  0
6  6      KR  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `tidyverse` option, where we put into long form, then group by the id, then if the column name is in the country column, then change to a 1. Then, we can pivot back to the wide form.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id, country)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(name %in% country, 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value")
```

**Output**

```
     id country    US    JP    CH    KR    BE    SP
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 US          1     1     0     0     0     0
2     1 JP          1     1     0     0     0     0
3     3 CH          1     0     1     0     0     0
4     3 US          1     0     1     0     0     0
5     5 KR          0     0     0     1     0     0
6     6 KR          0     0     0     1     0     0
```